# customize ClickOne publish.htm BEFORE it is pushed to the web server

Tags: clickonce, publish

This page describes how to customize the ClickOnce publish.htm page after it has been pushed to the web server:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5befhe3.aspx

But is it possible to make some changes, either to the wording or the font, of the publish.htm *template*, wherever it is, so that edits to its *non-dynamic* content and style could be done just once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to template the output.  The only option is to either auto generate the publish.htm page and then make your own necessary modifications after each update.  Option two is to do as the article suggests and create your own page and tell Visual Studio not to generate the publish page for you.

If you wanted to get fancy, you could create an install page that uses JavaScript to download the .application file and then parses out the dynamic information after each publication (i.e. version information.)

If you can solve your problem by using JS, post a question and answer it yourself (which is within the terms of StackOverflow) explaining how you used JS to parse the .application file.

I, personally, would like to check out such an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a template somewhere on your computer to generate it... But then you're stuck with the same template for every ClickOnce project...

I suggest you create a more dynamic page (.aspx) that can read the information from the .application file.